# How do I get gWaei to work in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, japanese

gWaei used to run in 11.10, but in 12.04 I get a blank window to open and it just hangs from there, requiring a force-quit to close.

[image]

I submitted a bug to the [gwaei launchpad bug report site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwaei/+bug/971240) and while there has been a response, I don't really understand much of it.

Can somebody explain to me in simple English how I can get this thing to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally released gWaei 3.6.1 which fixes these issues.  I'm trying to get this package in the 12.04 LTS release now, though the Ubuntu guys will probably be busy getting 12.10 out the door.

Comment: Where is this available? Can you make a PPA available?

Answer (score 4):

#### Known bug, fixed in Debian, please update from my PPA

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwaei/+bug/971240) with the *gwaei* version (3.2.0) bundled with Ubuntu 12.04 as you have noted. It has been fixed upstream (i.e. in Debian, where Ubuntu draws its packages from).

I have ported the fixed version 3.4.3 (and dependencies) to a PPA to allow Ubuntu users to easily solve this problem.

> Note: If you are unfamiliar with installing third-party software from PPAs, you may want to refer to these questions:
>
> - [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
> - [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

#### Solution: here's how...

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type/paste `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:izx/bleeding -y`
3. Then type `sudo apt-get update`
4. And finally, the below (press Y at the prompt):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gwaei libwaei2 zlib1g
   ```

That's it -- *gwaei* should now work!

[image]

Comment: Great stuff, thanks :)
Out of curiosity, are you on the gwaei team? Or just an interested party?

Comment: @BillO'Dwyer, neither; just interested from the perspective of helping fix something useful that shouldn't have been broken in 12.04 in the first place... :)

Comment: Well either way, you've been a great help - thanks!!

Comment: Only a minor problem, but there appears to be no menu function anymore... Not an issue, as I got everything done from the opening dictionary installation dialogue; just wondered if it was something that affected Debian?

Comment: It's done, Gwaei works with the menu now on Ubuntu 12.04. Please `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` @BillO'Dwyer, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible solution to me.

After I installed the software by

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:izx/bleeding -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gwaei libwaei2 zlib1g
```

The texlive packages were removed!

Moreover, I cannot re-install texlive package even I removed the repository of  ppa:izx/bleeding
and gwaei itself.

I am now have error information as below:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  texlive-base :
>   Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2009-10) but it is not going to be
>   installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

Comment: I successfully installed texlive-base by this command:

`sudo aptitude install texlive-base`  This command  gives you options to select from many proposed solutions, one of which is to downgrade gwaei.